# PubNub Twitter Data Stream setup doesn't return data

Tags: javascript, api, d3.js, twitter, pubnub

Trying to map tweets on a world map with D3 and using PubNub for the first time to get a real-time data stream. Having trouble with setting it up and got the following code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};

var w = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
            .append("svg")
              .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var geoData = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json";

d3.json(geoData, function(data){

    var geo = data.features;

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                       .scale(150)
                       .translate([w/2,h/2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
                     .projection(projection);

    svg.selectAll("path")
       .data(geo)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("fill", "#95E1D3")
       .attr("stroke", "#34495e")
       .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
       .attr("class", function(d){ return d.properties.name})
       .attr("d", path);

var pubnub = new PubNub({

     subscribeKey : "my key"

   });

    pubnub.subscribe({

    channels: ['pubnub-twitter'],

    withPresence: true

     });

   pubnub.addListener({

    message: function(m) {

        console.log(m);    

    },

   presence: function(p){

     console.log(p);

   },

   status: function(s){

     console.log(s);

   }

  })


})
```

I would expect it prints the messages to the console, but nothing happens. Using PubNub v4. Can anyone help me pls?

Here is a working Codepen:

http://codepen.io/chemok78/full/mRjXzb/

Comment: Reference link: [Tweet emotion: real-time Tweet analysis with PubNub Data Stream](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/tweet-emotion-real-time-tweet-analysis-with-pubnub-data-stream) - this is a similar project.

Comment: Yes you are right, this should be `console.log()`'ing.

Comment: Provided a working example http://stackoverflow.com/a/42095828/524733 of the Twitter tweets feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Twitter Sample Feed Streaming Tweets

The example following will print all tweets in a `console.log()`. You can test this yourself by clicking the "Run code snippet" button.  You will see a stream of tweets in your console.

```js
// Create PubNub Socket Handler
const pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey   : 'empty'
,   ssl          : true
,   subscribeKey : 'sub-c-78806dd4-42a6-11e4-aed8-02ee2ddab7fe'
});

// Subscribe to Twitter feed
console.log("Subscribing to Live Twitter Stream.");
pubnub.subscribe({ channels: ['pubnub-twitter'] });

// Add Socket Event Function Handlers
pubnub.addListener({
    status  : statusEvent => console.log(statusEvent)
,   message : message     => console.log(message)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

PubNub posted a blog in 2014 that demonstrates [how to analyze tweets from Twitter's Firehose](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-10-twitter-firehose-realtime-tweet-stream-analysis/).

[image: Twitter Tweet Feed Stream]